# RubyMonk: Kaprekar's number

Tags: ruby

I'm following the course at RubyMonk and I'm stuck on this problem:

> 9 is a Kaprekar number since: 9 ^ 2 = 81 and 8 + 1 = 9.
>   Find if a given number is a Kaprekar number

Using this, I keep getting `false` with each number:

```
def kaprekar?(k)
   k == k * k.to_s.chars.map(&:to_i).inject(:+)
end
```

Using this, I'm getting `true` for `9` (expected), and `false` for `55` and `19` (expected), but also `false` for `297` and `703` (should be `true`).

```
def kaprekar?(k)
  a = k * k
  k == a.to_s.chars.map(&:to_i).inject(:+)
 end
```

Here's the RubyMonk solution

```
def kaprekar?(k)
  no_of_digits = k.to_s.size
  square = (k ** 2).to_s

  second_half = square[-no_of_digits..-1]
  first_half = square.size.even? ? square[0..no_of_digits-1] : square[0..no_of_digits-2]

  k == first_half.to_i + second_half.to_i
end
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't compare code complexity until yours actually *works*... What's your question?

Comment: Your implementation is not based on definition of [Kaprekar Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaprekar_number)

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm just trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @MatthiasTotschnig  The definition says that square of number has to be split in two parts such that their sum is equal to original number - where are you splitting your square in two parts?  Please read the definition - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaprekar_number

Comment: @WandMaker Oh, ok. Got it. My method's splitting every digit. Is there a way using string#split to split a string into two parts?

Comment: @MatthiasTotschnig  You can delete the question if you wish or leave it open for answer from someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
def kaprekar?(k)
    sq=k**2
    k == [sq.to_s.slice(0..k.to_s.size-1),sq.to_s.slice(k.to_s.size..-1)].map(&:to_i).inject(:+)
end
```

This will take the square of the number, slice it, add both the parts and will return true or false accordingly.

For k = 1, 9, 45, 55, 99, 297, 703,... it returns true while for others the value is false.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on the same problem. This is my solution.  I don't understand why `k=297` would not pass?

```
def kaprekar?(k)
    str = (k**2).to_s
    n = k.to_s.length
    num2 = str.slice!(-n..-1).to_i
    num1 = str.slice!(0..str.length-n-1).to_i 
    num = num1 + num2
    if num == k
        return true
    else
        return false
    end
end
```

Comment: I don´t know either, but you can replace the if/else statement in your code by `return num == k`

Comment: A few days later looking back, my code is so un-DRY.  Thanks,  @MatthiasTotschnig